# Compile openssl version openssl-1.1.1w with VS2017

Tags: openssl

I am using old openssl version openssl-0.9.8i compiling with VS-2012.

Now I want to upgrade openssl version to openssl-1.1.1w with VS-2017.

Steps for compile I am using for openssl-0.9.8i are as below:

1. cd to openssl directory
2. perl Configure no-idea no-rc5 no-mdc2 no-threads shared VC-WIN64A &&  ms\do_win64a
3. nmake -f ms\ntdll.mak

Same I want to do with openssl-1.1.1w with VS-2017.

Can you please help me how to compile openssl-1.1.1w with VS-2017?

Can you please help me how to compile openssl-1.1.1w with VS-2017?